# Sound not coming out of headphones in Mint 18 cinnamon/ Fedora 24; speakers work fine

Tags: linux-mint, audio, alsa

The interesting thing is that the speakers on my computer work just fine. However, if I plug in my headphones, no sound comes out. The computer is a 2011 21.5 inch, i5 IMac, the specs of which [can be found here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.7-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html).

**Solutions Attempted**:

- Adding `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and restarting. This did not fix the problem.
- Opening up the `alsamixer` command in terminal and making sure that my headphones aren't muted there. They were not muted. [image: Headphones not muted].
- Adding a Fedora 24 partition to my system. I am not able to use my headphones in that partition either.

Comment: Are the headphones, and the headphone jack on the PC, both known to work?

Comment: @agc Yup. Before booting up linux mint they worked without issue on Mac OS 10.11. They continue to work well if I switch over to my OSX partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried digging again, and I found a solution on Fedora 24:

1. Create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf`
2. Add `options snd_hda_intel model=imac27_122` to the file
3. Reboot

Note: The [subsystem ID](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_sound_problems#Model_parameter) is 8086:7270.

Answer (score 1):

I get that it might no longer be relevant for you, but for other people coming running into this problem, I've had the same, took me days to figure out, but now I have got a very simple solutions that works well (I've reinstalled ubuntu so had to do it all again and kinda know the drill now):

This fix should work for every 2011 iMac 27 and 21 inch alike:

first open up terminal and enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add to the last line of the file:

> options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122

control+x - y to safe and then do the same in:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf
```

and again add to the last line:

> options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122

close and save it again, and reboot :)

(you have to add the iMac27_122 to both of the files or it still does nothing, though you might have changed one of the 2 already following other peoples instructions, I have to do this for every linux version I install, and I've already tried a few, none of them allow sound through the headphones on default)

if after this it still doesn't work type in terminal (don't undo your previous changes):
`alsamixer` and unmute all the muted channels with "M"

Comment: Great first post! Welcome to [unix.se]!

Answer (score 0):

I see your Auto Mute is enabled. Had this problem once and I switched that to Disabled. Worked after that.Although now I have a new problem after trying to install Pipelight as an alternative to Silverlight.So if anyone has any solutions beyond this that would be great.

Comment: I tried turning off `Auto Mute` and restarting, but the issue still persists. However, I do appreciate your input very much.

Answer (score 0):

[FabulousGlobe's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333405), which said

> 1. Create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf`
> 2. Add `options snd_hda_intel model=imac27_122` to the file
> 3. Reboot

worked perfectly.

For the benefit of anyone new to Linux, step-by-step instructions:

I did this from terminal by using:

1. `touch /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf`
2. `chown yourusername /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf`
3. Edit the file and add the line mentioned above and save it
4. Back to the terminal and `chown root /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf`
5. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in a very simple way

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer
```

[image]

I use it if necessary.